# The second emitter does not emit particles in the correct way

Tags: particles, physics, bezier-curves, drivers

I'm trying to create a traffic simulation using the blender particle systems with different model of cars. The enviroment consists of a two-lane road. I want the cars crossing the two lanes in opposite directions,so I have created two planes called **emitter_close** and **emitter_far** with two different particle systems attached. The plane called **emitter_close** is able to emit cars in the correct way,the opposite **emitter_far** does not do that. Infact when I attach a new particle system to the **emitter_far** which has the same parameters of the **emitter_close**,this is what happens :

[image: particles are missing]

These are the values that I have used for **both planes** :

1. Emissions Number = 300
2. Start / end = 1 - 320
3. Lifetime = 50
4. Random =   0
5. Emit From = Faces
6. Rotation = yes
7. Dynamic = yes
8. Render / Emitter = yes
9. Render / Group = Group_car_yellow / Group_car_green
10. Whole Group = yes
11. Size = 1.860
12. On the Physics tab is enabled the Force Field type = Curve Guide with 
     minimum distance = 1.000

Below you can see what's the orientation of the emitter_close normals and of the curve on the left road :

[image: normal's orientation emitter_close]
[image: curve orientation left road]

Below you can see what's the orientation of the emitter_far normals and of the curve on the right road :

[image: normal's orientation emitter_far]
[image: curve orientation right road]

you can also see that I created two groups. Inside each group there are the **main components of a car**,like :

1. Empty_car_ yellow or green
2. **4 wheels**,parented to the empty_car_yellow,with a driver configured on the X rotation and X location,with :

   - Expr = -var ;
   - object = empty_car_yellow ;
   - type = X location ;
   - space = world
3. **another 4 wheels**,parented to the empty_car_green,with a driver configured on the X rotation,with :

   - Expr = -var ;
   - object = empty_car_green ;
   - type = y location ;
   - space = world
4. the car's body meshes

Each car follow a path,that's represented by the **NurbsPath_road_sx** and the **NurbsPath_road_dx**,with the following parameters set :

- Path animation = yes
- Follow = yes
- Frames = 320

Instead,the road on the left is populated correctly with the cars,even if some of them need an obstacle to not get out of the carriageway :

[image: particles are ok]

If for the emitter_far I choose the **Group_car_yellow** instead of the **Group_car_green**,also the right road is populated correctly with cars :

[image: yellow_cars on the right road are ok]

There should be a problem with the settings of the green car. Below you can see how is configured :

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
[image: 5]
[image: 6]

but I don't know which. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.